# WP8 Isolated storage: Relative paths in a html page are not locating files. Must be absolute path

Tags: c#, html, cordova, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

When I save my files to the app's isolated storage on a WP8 device and navigate to a HTML file, any relative references to files in the same folder do not work as one would expect. For example:

```
<script src="myjavascript.js"></script>
<img src="myimage.png">
```

Using the following path, however, does work.

```
<script src="C:/Data/Users/DefApps/AppData/{17B7BC4F-D4CF-422F-90DD-CDE9C48AB77CA}/Local/myjavascript.js></script>
```

As I'm using cordova/phonegap I want to keep the file references consistent and it amazes me that the relative references don't seem to work in WP8's isolated storage. I'm looking for any solutions or suggestions as to what might work without having to hard-code paths into all of my files. Thanks.

Comment: HTML page must be located in the same isolated storage folder. Please double check this.

Comment: The whole point of isolated storage is to prevent apps that are outside of it from accessing it, hence isolated.

Comment: The HTML page is in the same folder in the isolated storage of the app, I've even tried putting them all at the root. I navigate to the html page using $.mobile.changePage("isostore:/mypage.html", {transition:  "slide", changeHash: false, showLoadMsg: false}).

Comment: I've just used window.location in the html file in question and the path is x-wmapp0://www/index.html which is the path of the app's main file that calls the $.mobile.changePage function. As I understand, the ajax call is just replacing the body of index.html with that of myPage.html. This could explain why the relative path is not working, although this problem does not exist on Android or IOS. Also I would then expect that placing the referenced JS file alongside index.html would fix this issue, but it still doesn't find the file.

Comment: I'm getting the same behavior using MS's new Multi-device Hybrid App template (which also uses Cordova).  I can't do single-page navigation on Win8 and WP8, but it works on Android.  Haven't tried iOS.